# Linear Electronic Circuits BJT

Tags: bjt, resistance

[image]While calculating the output resistance do I need to **short this voltage source resistance Rsig**?

Comment: Best if you include an image of the schematic, so you can ask: "do I need to short *this* voltage source resistance \$R_s\$". Otherwise it calls on the respondent to presume the circuit you're talking about, which is likely to lead to misleading answers.

Comment: @scanny do u have the answer

Comment: I'm sure I and many others can answer your question if you provide the schematic. Otherwise your question is ambiguous. Take a photo of it with your phone if a printed or hand-written copy is all you have. We just need to see the circuit you're looking at.

Comment: @scanny do u have the answer now,I haven't seen your comment properly before.

Comment: @The Photon  Check it out now

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no. When doing small signal analysis, DC voltage sources, such as \$V_{CC}\$ in this circuit, are shorted; but resistors are not. Current sources, such as \$I\$ in this circuit are opened (made an open circuit).

These are the transformations you see between the left-hand side of your circuit and the right-hand side. Note that, in the right-hand side, \$V_{CC}\$ is replaced by ground, and the current sources \$I\$ does not appear.

Although not shown explicitly in the left-hand circuit, the negative terminal of the \$V_{CC}\$ voltage source is connected to ground. That's why, when \$V_{CC}\$ is shorted, it simply becomes ground.

Comment: I am talking about the calculation part of the output resistance of the system Zo.For your information,while calculating Zo of the bjt,we short the signal voltage source,so what I am expecting from you is **when we short the signal source,the signal resistance also goes out of the circuit or not**?

Comment: No. Shorting the signal source, or any voltage source, means connecting its positive terminal to its negative terminal with a conductor. On a schematic, this amounts to replacing the source with a line/wire. In this case, the left-side terminal of \$R_{sig}\$ then has a direct connection to ground. You don't remove the resistance along with the signal voltage source.

Comment: I think the same but thinking practically,when we short the signal voltage source,the voltage of the  signal source falls across its internal resistance only.It would be better is u explain more elaborate?

Comment: @scanner Reply!!!